# Kotlin: Accessing parameter of when-statement

Tags: syntax, kotlin

Is there a way to get the value of the expression I passed into the `when` statement?

In my application I have a `KeyListener` like that

```
_content.addKeyListener(object : KeyAdapter() {
    override fun keyPressed(e: KeyEvent?) = when(e?.keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.VK_T -> mainWindow.enterTrainingState()
        KeyEvent.VK_P -> mainWindow.enterPlayState()
        KeyEvent.VK_E -> mainWindow.close()
        else -> println(e?.keyCode)
    }
})
```

Has Kotlin a neat syntax to access `e?.keyCode`? I don't really want to repeat the expression.

Comment: I read the above comment and beginning of the accepted answer and conclude that it not possible but its a 'yes' since Kotlin 1.3. See the accepted answer, and read till the end!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I had this problem myself a couple of days ago. I think it would have been nice to be able to access the value as `it` inside the `when`-expression.

I solved it by assigning the expression to a `val` before the `when` expression:

```
val keyCode = e?.keyCode
when(keyCode) {
    KeyEvent.VK_T -> mainWindow.enterTrainingState()
    KeyEvent.VK_P -> mainWindow.enterPlayState()
    KeyEvent.VK_E -> mainWindow.close()
    else -> println(keyCode)
}
```

Unfortunately, this would require you to add extra braces and lines. The upside though, is that `e?.keyCode` would only be evaluated once. It may not matter in this exact case, but if the expression was bigger, this approach would be suitable.

**Edit:**

Another possibility it to wrap the `when` expression in a call to `let`. It lets you access the parameter with `it`. Like this:

```
e?.keyCode.let {
    when(it) {
        KeyEvent.VK_T -> mainWindow.enterTrainingState()
        KeyEvent.VK_P -> mainWindow.enterPlayState()
        KeyEvent.VK_E -> mainWindow.close()
        else -> println(it)
  }
}
```

**Edit2:**

Kotlin 1.3 has support for capturing the subject expression of a `when` in a variable. This is the syntax:

```
when(val keyCode = e?.keyCode) {
    KeyEvent.VK_T -> mainWindow.enterTrainingState()
    KeyEvent.VK_P -> mainWindow.enterPlayState()
    KeyEvent.VK_E -> mainWindow.close()
    else -> println(keyCode)
}
```

Comment: Which, in this case, will turn the OP’s expression into a block, thus requiring extra braces and lines.

Comment: Accessing it via `it` was my first idea too... but sadly it is not possible (would be cool if it was possible). And as Michael already mentioned your solution converts my expression into a block.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel Yes, that is why I said it would be nice if we could access it with `it`. This possibility has one purpose, which is that `e?.keyCode` would only be evaluated once. It may not make a difference in this case, but if it was a bigger expression, I would say this is the way to go.

Comment: @Exhauzt See my edit and see if you find that to be better.

Comment: @Exhauzt I wonder what made this answer so much better than mine…

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I think we both came up with that approach at the same time. I saw your answer after I posted my edit. I gave you an upvote :)

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I just saw his answer first that's the only reason

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible as of Kotlin 1.1. There is an open feature request for this functionality: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4895

Answer (score 4):

You may try the following, even if it changes the semantics slightly. In your case it may well be OK, I guess.

```
_content.addKeyListener(object : KeyAdapter() {
    override fun keyPressed(e: KeyEvent?) = e?.keyCode.let {
        when(it) {
            KeyEvent.VK_T -> mainWindow.enterTrainingState()
            KeyEvent.VK_P -> mainWindow.enterPlayState()
            KeyEvent.VK_E -> mainWindow.close()
            else -> println(it)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

With Kotlin 1.3, you can set the parameter as a scoped variable and access it.

```
_content.addKeyListener(object : KeyAdapter() {
    override fun keyPressed(e: KeyEvent?) = when(val keycode = e?.keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.VK_T -> mainWindow.enterTrainingState()
        KeyEvent.VK_P -> mainWindow.enterPlayState()
        KeyEvent.VK_E -> mainWindow.close()
        else -> println(keycode)
    }
})
```